# Adding class wont override current class

Tags: jquery, html, css

Trying to add a class that gives the effect of dismissing a notification..

so i have this

```
   <div onclick="ifRead()" id="messageList">

      </div>
```

and then once i click a button to view the messages a class gets added

```
  <div onclick="ifRead()" id="messageList" class=" readClass">

      </div>
```

then if I click on the message the `font-weight` changes from bold to normal which is correct but the `background-color` does not change even though I have told it to be none... and also the `content` does not disappear:

```
.readClass {
  font-weight: normal;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: none !important;
  content: ""
}

.msgs:after {
  content: "1"
}

.msgs {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100px;
}
```

any idea why it isn't overriding?

all js code:

```
function myfunc() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myParagraph1");
  x.className += " myClass"
}

function sendMsg() {
  var msg = document.getElementById('msg').value;
  var msgObj = {
    sender: 'Bob',
    receiver: 'Paul',
    read: false,
    body: msg
  }
  messagesArray.push(msgObj)
}

function ifRead() {
  readMsg();
  if (messagesArray[0].read === true){
    var x = document.getElementById('messageList');
    x.className += " readClass"
  }
}

function readMsg() {
  messagesArray[0].read = true;
}

function viewMsgs(){
  var node = document.createElement("p");
  node.className = "msgs";
  var value = document.getElementById('msg').value;
  node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(value));
  document.getElementById('messageList').appendChild(node);
}
```

Comment: Where is your 'ifRead' code?

Comment: please provide js code

Comment: What element has the `msgs` class? If it's an element that *contains* the `#messageList` element, then setting a transparent background of the message list won't change anything.

Comment: @NagaSaiA added

Answer (score 2):

`none` is not a valid value for `background-color`. See the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color).  Set it to `transparent` to explicitly remove it.

But, a better approach is to add a class that specifies a background color and then just remove that class when appropriate. By doing this, you don't have to specify the color to go to. Removing the class just reverts the element back to its original styling.

Also, elements support a **[`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)** property, which itself supports: `add()`, `remove()` and `toggle()` methods making it very easy to work with classes (easier than `className`).

Here's a simple example:

```js
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.getElementById("btn").classList.toggle("backgroundOn");
});
```

```css
.backgroundOn {
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="btn">Click Me to Toggle Classes</div>
```

Comment: and `content:none` should be added to the `:after`/`:before` rule they want to change.

Answer (score 0):

The background color Yellow is being applied to whatever container you've put .msgs class on.

From the code you've provided, there is no background color being applied to messageList div for you to remove.

Answer (score 0):

I think msg class is parent for the redclass. That is why background of redclass is none but background of msg will still be there. It will helpful if you share the code.